# Why is Reset Button is not working in given HTML code?

Tags: html, forms

Code of the form where reset button is not working. This a form that gathers information of a student.

It uses Labels, text-fields, text-area, radio-buttons, Check-Box, Submit Button, Reset Button etc.

The reset button is not functioning in this code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    label.la {
      text-indent: 30px;
      color: red;
      width: 240px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
  <style type="text/css">
    input.tf {
      border-color: green;
      border: 2px solid
    }
  </style>
  <style type="text/css">
    #b1:hover {
      background-color: red;
      color: white
    }
    
    #b2:hover {
      background-color: green;
      color: white
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center">
  <h1>Assignment 3</h1>
  <from style="display:inline-block;" action="/action_page.php">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <h3>Student Info</h3>
      </legend>
      <label class="la">First Name:</label>
      <input class="tf" type="text" placeholder="Jadon" required>
      <br><br>
      <label class="la">Last Name:</label>
      <input class="tf" type="text" placeholder="Sancho" required>
      <br><br>
      <label class="la">Date of Birth:</label>
      <input class="tf" type="text" placeholder="1/1/1999" required>
      <br><br>
      <label class="la">Age:</label>
      <input class="tf" type="text" placeholder="20" required>
      <br><br>
      <label class="la" style="padding-right: 30px">Gender:</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Male" value="Male">
      <label>Male</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Female" value="Female">
      <label for="Female">Female</label>
      <br><br>
      <label style="color:red;display:inline;padding-left: 60px;width: 210px;display: inline-block;margin:-top:20px">Address:</label>
      <textarea cols="25" rows="3" placeholder="type here..." style="border-color: green;border:2px solid;margin-top: : 50px"></textarea>
      <br><br>
      <label class="la" style="padding-left: 55px">Class:</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Class" value="F.Y">
      <label>F.Y</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Class" value="S.Y">
      <label>S.Y</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Class" value="T.Y">
      <label>T.Y</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Class" value="B.Tech">
      <label>B.Tech</label>
      <br><br>
      <label class="la" style="padding-left: 95px">Area(s) of Interest:</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="M.L">
      <label for="M.L">M.L</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="A.I">
      <label for="A.I">A.I</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="H.P.C">
      <label for="H.P.C">H.P.C</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Cyber-Security">
      <label for="Cyber-Security">Cyber-Security</label>
      <br><br>
      <label class="la">E-mail:</label>
      <input class="tf" type="text" placeholder="JSancho07@gmail.com" required>
      <br><br>
      <label class="la">Password:</label>
      <input class="tf" type="Password" placeholder="min 8 characters" required>
      <br><br>
      <input id="b1" type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" style="border-color: red;font-size: 20px;border-radius: 15%;margin:10px">
      <input id="b2" type="submit" name="submit" style="border-color: green;font-size: 20px;border-radius: 15%;margin: 10px" onclick="myFunction()">
      <script>
        function myFunction() {
          alert("Submission Successful");
        }
      </script>
    </fieldset>
  </from>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think you have a typo in your code, you need to change your `<from />` element to `<form />`, perhaps then it will work?

Comment: Both elements are spelled wrong <form></form>, then it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    label.la {
      text-indent: 30px;
      color: red;
      width: 240px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
  <style type="text/css">
    input.tf {
      border-color: green;
      border: 2px solid
    }
  </style>
  <style type="text/css">
    #b1:hover {
      background-color: red;
      color: white
    }
    
    #b2:hover {
      background-color: green;
      color: white
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center">
  <h1>Assignment 3</h1>
  <form style="display:inline-block;" action="/action_page.php">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <h3>Student Info</h3>
      </legend>
      <label class="la">First Name:</label>
      <input class="tf" type="text" placeholder="Jadon" required>
      <br><br>
      <label class="la">Last Name:</label>
      <input class="tf" type="text" placeholder="Sancho" required>
      <br><br>
      <label class="la">Date of Birth:</label>
      <input class="tf" type="text" placeholder="1/1/1999" required>
      <br><br>
      <label class="la">Age:</label>
      <input class="tf" type="text" placeholder="20" required>
      <br><br>
      <label class="la" style="padding-right: 30px">Gender:</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Male" value="Male">
      <label>Male</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Female" value="Female">
      <label for="Female">Female</label>
      <br><br>
      <label style="color:red;display:inline;padding-left: 60px;width: 210px;display: inline-block;margin:-top:20px">Address:</label>
      <textarea cols="25" rows="3" placeholder="type here..." style="border-color: green;border:2px solid;margin-top: : 50px"></textarea>
      <br><br>
      <label class="la" style="padding-left: 55px">Class:</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Class" value="F.Y">
      <label>F.Y</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Class" value="S.Y">
      <label>S.Y</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Class" value="T.Y">
      <label>T.Y</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Class" value="B.Tech">
      <label>B.Tech</label>
      <br><br>
      <label class="la" style="padding-left: 95px">Area(s) of Interest:</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="M.L">
      <label for="M.L">M.L</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="A.I">
      <label for="A.I">A.I</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="H.P.C">
      <label for="H.P.C">H.P.C</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Cyber-Security">
      <label for="Cyber-Security">Cyber-Security</label>
      <br><br>
      <label class="la">E-mail:</label>
      <input class="tf" type="text" placeholder="JSancho07@gmail.com" required>
      <br><br>
      <label class="la">Password:</label>
      <input class="tf" type="Password" placeholder="min 8 characters" required>
      <br><br>
      <input id="b1" type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" style="border-color: red;font-size: 20px;border-radius: 15%;margin:10px">
      <input id="b2" type="submit" name="submit" style="border-color: green;font-size: 20px;border-radius: 15%;margin: 10px" onclick="myFunction()">
      <script>
        function myFunction() {
          alert("Submission Successful");
        }
      </script>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```